# Background color of fields according to input - SharePoint Online List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json, status

I know nothing about JSON but I need to get JSON that will allow me to set the background color field of a "Status" field based on the selected "Status" - i.e selection of yellow  will result in Yellow Background".

I am using a SharePoint List Project Plan in Project Online and it will not allow use of column formatting.

Comment: Are you unable to use JSON column formatting? Are you using modern experience SharePoint online list?

Comment: By Project online do you mean you are using Microsoft Project for web which URL would be like https://project.microsoft.com?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you: [Conditional classes based on the value in a text or choice field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-list-formatting#example-conditional-classes-based-on-the-value-in-a-text-or-choice-field)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if([$Status] == 'Done', 'sp-field-severity--good', if([$Status] == 'In progress', 'sp-field-severity--low' ,if([$Status] == 'In review','sp-field-severity--warning', if([$Status] == 'Has issues','sp-field-severity--blocked', ''))))"
}
```